# Execute linux shell command when voltage detected in GPIO pin's

Tags: embedded-linux, gpio

I would start with embedded Linux systems. I have experience in linux system's administration, but I have very little knowledge of electricity, electronics , or direct hardware access from Linux.

I've created an image with a small scheme for to explain my idea:

[View schema](http://imgur.com/8A2sXyg)

I would like to do:

1. The motherboard receives, upon conversion , 3.3 volt
2. In the GPIO pins , motherboard receives directly, once a button is pressed , 3.3 volt
3. I would like to get continously monitored these GPIO pins , to execute a command when the electricity arrives

My questions are:

a) Do you think Is this possible ?

b ) Do you know any source code sample, that allows control when electricity reaches a pin's GPIO ?

c ) Do you know any online store to buy voltage converter?

Thank you in advance and please, excuse me for my poor english level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Yes, this is very possible, through the use of an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Introduction) or other I/O device. [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) is not the only GPIO device out there, but it is very popular.

B) A library of code examples is shown at the [Arduino site](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Linux).

C) Wikipedia has a [list of electronic component sellers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Electronic_component_distributors). Once you have determined what the requirements will be, you will be able to find a converter at one of them.

Comment: Thank you so much K7AAY. Finally I've bought a raspberry pi 2 with a starter kit:

http://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B00KL6AC7O?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s01

I hope that it will be easier to start whit a raspberry!

Thank you again.